# How does DevTools determine an object's constructor's name?

Tags: javascript, constructor, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using Chrome v22.0.1229.94 m, not that it should matter, but just in case :-)

*Portability is of no concern to me.  As long as it works with Chrome (and Safari) I'm happy.*

I have two functions, foo and bar:

```
var foo = function() {
  ...
}
function bar() {
  ...
}
```

then if I create objects using them:

```
f1 = new foo();
b1 = new bar();
```

I can get the constructor's name for bar, but nor for foo:

```
> f1.constructor.name  ==> ""
> b1.constructor.name  ==> "bar"
```

yet in both cases DevTools console will show the names "foo" and "bar" when I inspect the variables **f1** and **b1**.

How do I extract the **name** *foo* for **f1** as DevTools is able to?

[image]

Comment: This is interesting. It's like devtools name the anonymous function arbitrary. Watch this too: `var foo = function myfoo(){}; 
new foo();  
==> myfoo`

Comment: @Mohsen thanks for the screen grab and your supporting comment.

Comment: This is an awesome question, and I cannot believe this isn't possible to get this name from the function myself... I need it :D Any luck finding a solution??

Answer (score 8):

V8 can perform function name inference at the parsing stage, exposing this information via its APIs. You will not be able to extract this info using the normal object properties.

Comment: I'm not adverse to using V8 API (don't need portability).  Are you able to point me in the direction of that API's documentation.

Answer (score 2):

In the case for `foo`, you're creating a *function expression*. That means, you're assigning an *anonymous function* to a variable.

You can't resolve the function `name` programatically like that, unless you give the function a name and create a "*named function expression*".

```
var foo = function foo() {
  ...
}
```

Comment: His question is how developer tools shows an object named `foo` in return of `new foo()`?