# Are class declarations subject to scope in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, oop, class, scope

Thinking about how JavaScript uses functions for scoping of variables, I started to think about what would happen in case of the following example:

```
var OuterClass = function () {

    var InnerClass = function () {
        this.foo = "bar";
    };

    this.getInstanceOfInner = function () {
        return new InnerClass();
    };

};

var instanceOfOuter = new OuterClass();
console.log(instanceOfOuter.getInstanceOfInner());
```

[**Fiddle of the above**](http://jsfiddle.net/vfydN/)

Testing the above code in different browsers, the outcome varies:

- **Chrome:** Logs an instance of the inner-class and seems to be aware of the class declaration.
- **Firefox:** Seems to log an "untyped" object, but with the correct properties.
- **IE9:** Logs the string-representation of an object `[object Object]`

*I got somewhat confused about this, what is the deal here? Are class declarations subject to scope, the same way other variables are? Or is it up to each vendor to implement it as they please?*

Comment: Uh what? The only difference I see is how different consoles handle `Object` instances representation in the console. Do a `console.log(instanceOfOuter.getInstanceOfInner().foo)` and you will get the same string result on all browsers.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Yes that is true, but in Chrome you get an instance of the inner-class, which I would have expected to be out of scope. The class shouldn't be known in the outer scope. Firefox on the other hand seem to log an untyped object, which seems more appropriate, if classes are subject to the same scoping as other variables. What I wonder if is the class declaration should be known in the outer scope or not.

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson - Even though the name `InnerClass` is invisible to the outside scope, its definition is visible outside once you return `new InnerClass()` from `OuterClass.getInstanceOfInner()`

Comment: Chrome simply displays a reference to which function created the object. For example, open the console on this page then type `$('*')`. Chrome shows `e.fn.e.init` which is the the function that creates new instances of jQuery objects, while Firefox will display an "untyped" object.

Comment: See related http://stackoverflow.com/q/12944719/1331430

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no classes and instances in JavaScript, just prototypes and constructor *functions* (read about the differences [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model)). Those follow the same scoping rules as any other objects. So the constructor function `InnerClass` itself is not available outside of `ÒuterClass` but the returned "instance" knows its prototype and browsers may or may not log that.

Comment: Thank you, together with @Fabrício's reference in his comment on the question, this clarifies why Chrome can give a proper name to the returned object.